# Need somehelp get data from checkbox in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, uicomponent, knockoutjs, checkbox

I have used `Aheadworks_OneStepCheckout` and I added some checkbox.

However, I can't get the value of the checkbox.
My code:

> ```
> /**  * Copyright 2019 aheadWorks. All rights reserved.  * See
> LICENSE.txt for license details.  */
>
> define(
> [
>     'uiComponent',
>     'Aheadworks_OneStepCheckout/js/model/checkout-data',
>     'Aheadworks_OneStepCheckout/js/model/order-note/contact-type'
> ],
> function (Component, checkoutData, contactType) {
>     'use strict';
>
>     return Component.extend({
>         defaults: {
>             template: 'Aheadworks_OneStepCheckout/sidebar/contact-type',
>             inputValue: ''
>         },
>         isVisible: true,
>
>         /**
>          * @inheritdoc
>          */
>         initialize: function () {
>             var contactType = checkoutData.getContactType();
>             console.log('====='+ contactType);
>             this._super();
>
>             if (contactType) {
>                 this.inputValue(contactType);
>             }
>             this.inputValue.subscribe(function (newValue) {
>                 checkoutData.setContactType(newValue);
>             }, this);
>         },
>
>         /**
>          * @inheritdoc
>          */
>         initObservable: function () {
>             this._super();
>             this.inputValue = contactType;
>             return this;
>         },
>         contactPhone : function () {
>             console.log(this.checked);
>             console.log(this.val());
>             return data.val();
>         },
>     });
> } );
> ```

Template:

```
<div class="aw-sidebar_contact-type" data-bind="visible: isVisible">
    <span data-role="title" class="toggle" data-bind="i18n:'Contacts'"></span>
    <div class="content" data-role="content">
        <input data-role="contact-type-input"
               data-bind="value: inputValue" id="contacttype" type="textbox" value="1" class="checkbox"> <label></label>

        <div class="contact">
            <div class="aw-onestepcheckout-general-form-field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input data-bind="value: contactPhone, click: function(){jQuery('#contacttype').val}" type="checkbox" id="contact[phone]" name="contact_phone" value="1" class="checkbox"> <label></label>
                </div>
                <label for="contact[phone]" data-bind="click: onSubmit" style="width:85%">1.Call or Text My Cell Phone</label>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="aw-onestepcheckout-general-form-field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input  type="checkbox" id="contact[local]" name="contact_local" value="1" class="checkbox"> <label></label>
                </div>
                <label for="contact[local]"  data-bind="click: onSubmit" style="width:85%">2.I will call you from a local land line when i check in and provide you with my information</label>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="aw-onestepcheckout-general-form-field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input  type="checkbox" id="contact[whassap]" name="contact_whassap" value="1" class="checkbox"> <label></label>
                </div>
                <label for="contact[whassap]" data-bind="click: onSubmit" style="width:85%">3.Contact me via whats app</label>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="aw-onestepcheckout-general-form-field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input  type="checkbox" id="contact[caretaker]" name="contact_caretaker" value="1" class="checkbox"> <label></label>
                </div>
                <label for="contact[caretaker]" data-bind="click: onSubmit" style="width:85%">4.Contact the concerige/Properity Caretaker </label>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="aw-onestepcheckout-general-form-field">
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="contact[room]" name="contact_room" value="1" class="checkbox"> <label></label>
                </div>
                <label for="contact[room]" data-bind="click: onSubmit" style="width:85%">5.I have provied my room number - Call My Room"</label>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Expect: when I checkbox in the list. All value will push to textbox id **contacttype**

Comment: anyone in here?